# Sorting Y axis values when Y is not defined but instead there is fill=as.factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am newbie at R and I am trying to make a chart separated by percentage share. I managed to make a chart but I am unable to sort it decreasingly. I searched a lot of sort topics on Stackoverflow but I could not find a way that would work in my case (I think it is because I dont have y defined).

Here is my code:

```
  ggplot(wyzwania,aes(Etap.edukacji, fill= as.factor(Jakie.sa.Twoim.zdaniem.najwieksze.wyzwania.dla.nauczycieli.zwiazane.z.przejsciem.do.nauki.online.zdalnej.))) +       
      geom_bar(stat="count", position = "fill", color="black") + 
      theme(text = element_text(size=18))+
      labs(title = "Wykres przedstawiajacy opinie ankietowanych o wyzwaniach stawianych przed nauczycielami", x="Stopien edukacji", y="Liczba odpowiedzi", fill="Wyzwania stawiane przed nauczycielami")
```

Here is how it looks like:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Data:

```
structure(list(Plec = c("mezczyzna", "mezczyzna", "kobieta", 
"kobieta", "kobieta", "mezczyzna"), Etap.edukacji = c("studia", 
"studia", "studia", "studia", "studia", "studia"), Z.jakiego.urzadzenia.najczesciej.korzystasz.podczas.e.lekcji. = c("Komputer stacjonarny", 
"Komputer stacjonarny", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Komputer stacjonarny"
), Jakie.Twoim.zdaniem.sa.zalety.prowadzenia.zajec.zdalnie. = c("Uczestniczenie w zajeciach bez potrzeby wychodzenia z domu", 
"Uczestniczenie w zajeciach bez potrzeby wychodzenia z domu", 
"Uczestniczenie w zajeciach bez potrzeby wychodzenia z domu", 
"Uczestniczenie w zajeciach bez potrzeby wychodzenia z domu", 
"Uczestniczenie w zajeciach bez potrzeby wychodzenia z domu", 
"Uczestniczenie w zajeciach bez potrzeby wychodzenia z domu|Dostep do nagranych zajec"
), Wady.zajec.online = c("Brak kontaktu z rowiesnikami|Problemy z koncentracja", 
"Brak kontaktu z rowiesnikami|Problemy z koncentracja", "Problemy z koncentracja", 
"Problemy z koncentracja", "Problemy z koncentracja", "Problemy ze zrozumieniem nowych tresci|Problemy z koncentracja"
), Jaki.typ.prowadzenia.zajec.wolisz. = c("stacjonarnie", "stacjonarnie", 
"stacjonarnie", "stacjonarnie", "stacjonarnie", "zdalnie/online"
), Jak.radzisz.sobie.z.nauczaniem.zdalnym. = c(5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L), Jak.Twoim.zdaniem.radza.sobie.nauczycie.z.nauczaniem.zdalnym. = c(4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Myslac.o.Twojej.szkole.ktore.stwierdzenie.najlepiej.oddaje.doswiadczenie.nauczycieli.w.zakresie.nauczania.online. = c("Posiadaja uprzednie doswiadczenie w nauczaniu online", 
"Posiadaja uprzednie doswiadczenie w nauczaniu online", "Jest to ich pierwsza stycznosc z nauczaniem online", 
"Jest to ich pierwsza stycznosc z nauczaniem online", "Jest to ich pierwsza stycznosc z nauczaniem online", 
"Posiadaja uprzednie doswiadczenie w nauczaniu online"), Co.stanowiloby.najlepsze.wsparcie.dla.nauczycieli.w.nauczaniu.online.podczas.zamkniecia.szkol. = c("Szybkie kursy nauczania online|Mozliwosc kontaktowania sie z nauczycielami o wiekszym doswiadczeniu np. nauczycielami informatyki|Webinaria dla nauczycieli w celu podzielenia sie pomyslami i wyzwaniami", 
"Szybkie kursy nauczania online|Mozliwosc kontaktowania sie z nauczycielami o wiekszym doswiadczeniu np. nauczycielami informatyki|Webinaria dla nauczycieli w celu podzielenia sie pomyslami i wyzwaniami", 
"Szybkie kursy nauczania online|Nagrania wideo/scenariusze zajec obejmujace dobre praktyki|Webinaria dla nauczycieli w celu podzielenia sie pomyslami i wyzwaniami", 
"Szybkie kursy nauczania online|Nagrania wideo/scenariusze zajec obejmujace dobre praktyki|Webinaria dla nauczycieli w celu podzielenia sie pomyslami i wyzwaniami", 
"Szybkie kursy nauczania online|Nagrania wideo/scenariusze zajec obejmujace dobre praktyki|Webinaria dla nauczycieli w celu podzielenia sie pomyslami i wyzwaniami", 
"Webinaria dla nauczycieli w celu podzielenia sie pomyslami i wyzwaniami"
), Jakie.sa.Twoim.zdaniem.najwieksze.wyzwania.dla.nauczycieli.zwiazane.z.przejsciem.do.nauki.online.zdalnej. = c("Brak kompetencji pedagogicznych nauczycieli w nauczaniu online", 
"Utrzymywanie motywacji i uwagi uczniow.", "Dostep do  technologii(komputerow/oprogramowania/stabilnego lacza internetowego itd.)", 
"Brak kompetencji pedagogicznych nauczycieli w nauczaniu online", 
"Utrzymywanie motywacji i uwagi uczniow.", "Dostep do  technologii(komputerow/oprogramowania/stabilnego lacza internetowego itd.)"
), Ze.wzgledu.na.obecne.warunki.zwiazane.z.wirusem.COVID.19.czy.myslisz.ze.po.ponownym.otwarciu.szkol.nauczanie.online.zdalne.pozostanie.wsrod.praktyk.szkolnych. = c("Szkoly wroca do wczesniejszych praktyk", 
"Szkoly wroca do wczesniejszych praktyk", "Szkoly wroca do punktu wyjscia z niewielkimi zmianami", 
"Szkoly wroca do punktu wyjscia z niewielkimi zmianami", "Szkoly wroca do punktu wyjscia z niewielkimi zmianami", 
"Szkoly nieco sie zmienia: uwzgledniajac wiecej nauczania online niz kiedys."
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would be really thankful for any tips!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugWWy.png

Comment: Hi Alexiej. You have posted a few similar questions now. You would get an answer far more quickly and efficiently if you share your data with us. A plot requires both data and code to work, so we cannot test possible solutions unless we have your data. Can you type `dput(wyzwania)` into your console and paste the results into your question?

Comment: Sorry I am adding the data right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package [`forcats`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/), which is also a part of `tidyverse` (like `ggplot2`), you can reorder the factor usinf `fct_infreq()`, like so:

```
ggplot(wyzwania,aes(Etap.edukacji, fill= fct_infreq(as.factor(Jakie.sa.Twoim.zdaniem.najwieksze.wyzwania.dla.nauczycieli.zwiazane.z.przejsciem.do.nauki.online.zdalnej.)))) +       
  geom_bar(stat="count", position = "fill", color="black") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=18))+
  labs(title = "Wykres przedstawiajacy opinie ankietowanych o wyzwaniach stawianych przed nauczycielami", x="Stopien edukacji", y="Liczba odpowiedzi", fill="Wyzwania stawiane przed nauczycielami")
```

This should work, but because you didn't put a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't test it.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I wrote the wrong function in the code, even though I did it right in the beginning... I did `fct_reorder()` instead of `fct_infreq()`! I edited it, so it should work this time...